# How can do load testing of an code-igniter custom application?

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter, testing, load

I have developed an web-application for doing on-line exam. And the exam comes with more than 35K traffic concurrently. Before launching this application i need to test the performance of this application.

The application comes with optional questions and answers. Is there any specific tool for doing a load test in such applications ?

Comment: How many queries per second?

Comment: Do you expect to have 35K connections to MySQL open at the same time?  A practical limit is only a few thousand, and that takes some amount of RAM.  Connections that are actually performing queries -- you might get 64 in version 5.7.  After that, latency goes to hell.

Comment: per user 8queries for quesiton ,answers and update. We expect 8000 users in 3hrs

Comment: Only a few queries/second.  MySQL can easily handle hundreds of simple queries per second.  (So, I am not worried about MySQL; I cannot speak for code-igniter.)

Comment: CodeIgniter can easily handle it, it depends on your code and queries. If the code is doing things in an unoptimised way it will required more time to complete the requests. Also the SQL queries will run fine if they are optimised and all the indexes are correctly defined. However there are so many factors involved it is very difficult for anyone to say you can do 100's of queries per second, if the queries take ages to run. The only way to truly test it is a load/stress test to see how your server performs.

Comment: Mic: how can do the load/stress test for an custom CI application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using a tool like [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which will allow you to stress test your application or API's.

There is also another solution called [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).

Im not sure if there is one that will specifically do exactly what you want but both of these will allow you to stress test your application.